# How to subset a data frame by removing all rows from columns with a given string, and value less than X?

Tags: r, subset

I am trying to subset a data frame in R... I would like to remove all rows where the value is >0 in all columns with the word 'Blank' in it.

Ex input) df

`ID OTU1 OTU2 Blank1 Blank2
1   5    0     0       2
2   3    3     0       0
3   0    9     5       0
4   2    0     0       0`

Desired output

`ID OTU1 OTU2 Blank1 Blank2 
 2   3    3     0       0
 4   2    0     0       0`

I can do this individually by column with 
`df2=subset(df, subset=!(Blank1>0 | Blank2>0))`

I would like to change this so that it searches for all columns with the word 'Blank' in it, then removes rows where in those columns there is a value greater than 0.

I am trying `df2=subset(df, subset=!((grepl("Blank",colnames(df)))>0))` but it does not work correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the grepl function I would use the following code:

```
df2 <- df[apply(df[,grepl("Blank",names(df))],1,sum)==0,]
```

To break that up...

`apply` applies a function by either row or column, the `1` argument tells it to do rows. By applying `sum` I'll get something non-zero if there's any zeros. If there's a possibility of negative values change `sum` to `function(x){sum(abs(x))}` which will instead take the absolute value of the cell before summing them.

Once I've applied the `sum` function I just check to grab only those values which are 0 :)

We wrap all that into the row argument for 'df' and we get returned only those rows that we want.

Good luck!

Comment: Glad it helps :) Remember to mark this as the answer if you're happy with it.

Comment: @s.shi yes, when you ask for help on stack overflow, you should reward those who help you with upvotes and marking their solutions as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `dput` next time to provide a reproducible example. Given that, this code should work (but I did not test it):

```
df <- df[rowSums(df[, grepl("Blank", colnames(df))]) > 0, ]
```

Edit: This does the exact opposite of what was asked. Here you go:

```
df[rowSums(df[, grepl("Blank", colnames(df))]) == 0, ]
```

Comment: This wont give the output needed but rather opposite of what is actually needed

Comment: Ah, you are right @Onyambu: _"I would like to remove all rows where the value is >0"_ I only kept the rowsthat were supposed to be removed. I'll edit my anser.

Answer (score 0):

This should work too:

```
df[!(apply(df[,c("Blank1","Blank2")] > 0,1,sum) > 0),]
```